# Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names using map_df in purrr

Tags: r, error-handling, dplyr, purrr

I'm using the spotifyr package to scrape spotify audio features for every song of specific albums in my dataset. My issue is that my dataset consists of some artists that are not on spotify -- so they shouldn't be returning any values.

My issue is that when I get to an artist that is not on spotify, I get this error:

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names
```

I've tried wrapping the function in tryCatch to get `NA` for each column of the problematic row, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's an example of my code (FYI, you need to get API access from spotify's website to run the spotifyr code)

```
library(readr)
library(spotifyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = "xxx") #xxx will be from spotify's website
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = "xxx")
access_token <- get_spotify_access_token()

artist <- c("Eminem", "Chris Stapleton", "Brockhampton", "Big Sean, Metro Boomin")
album <- c("Revival", "From A Room: Volume 2", "SATURATION III", "Double or Nothing")
mydata <- data_frame(artist, album)

get_album_data <- function(x) {
  get_artist_audio_features(mydata$artist[x], return_closest_artist = TRUE) %>%
    filter(album_name == mydata$album[x])}

try_get_album_data <- function(x) {
  tryCatch(get_album_data(x), error = function(e) {NA})}

map_df(seq(1, 4), try_get_album_data)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that when it binds the rows, it cannot bind with `NA`. To fix this just use `data.frame()` rather than `NA`.

Here's a simpler example of the problem.

```
library('dplyr')
library('purrr')

try_filter <- function(df) {
  tryCatch(
    df %>%
      filter(Sepal.Length == 4.6),
    error = function(e) NA)
}

map_df(
  list(iris, NA, iris),
  try_filter)
#> Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names
```

The solution is to replace `NA` with `data.frame()`.

```
try_filter <- function(df) {
  tryCatch(
    df %>%
      filter(Sepal.Length == 4.6),
    error = function(e) data.frame())
}

map_df(
  list(iris, NA, iris),
  try_filter)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
#> 3          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 5          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 6          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
#> 7          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa
#> 8          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul, helped me a lot!

Comment: I was running into a similar issue where I had something like `map_dfr(1:100, function_that_returns_named_vector)`. Simply changing that function to return a `data.frame` instead allowed me to use this tool. The original function ended with `return(c("foo"=foo, "bar"=bar))`.  It did not produce an `NA`, it was just not the thing `map_dfr` was looking for. The one that worked ended in `return(data.frame("foo"=foo, "bar"=bar))`.

Comment: in my specific case a simple `data.frame()` didn't work, but `data.frame(a = NA)`or `tibble(a = NA)`did.