# Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Here is a code snippet:

```
y <- purrr::map(1:2, ~ c(a=.x))
test1 <- dplyr::bind_rows(y)
test2 <- do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, y)
```

The first call to `bind_rows` (`test1`) generates the error

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names
```

Using `do.call` to invoke `bind_rows` (`test2`), on the other hand, works as expected:

```
test2
# A tibble: 2 x 1
      a
  <int>
1     1
2     2
```

Why? This is using dplyr 0.7.6 and purrr 0.2.5. If I use `map_df` instead of `map`, it fails with the same error.

Note: It doesn't appear to me that this question is the same as [Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names using map_df in purrr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512461/error-in-bind-rows-x-id-argument-1-must-have-names-using-map-df-in-purrr).

EDIT: The other way to address this issue is by explicitly creating a dataframe in the first place:

```
y <- purrr::map(1:2, ~ data.frame(a=.x))
```

`test1` and `test2` are now created with no errors and are identical.

Alternatively,this creates the `test2` data frame in one step:

```
purrr::map_df(1:2, ~ data.frame(a=.x))
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the documentation of `bind_rows`:

> Note that for historical reasons, lists containg vectors are always
>   treated as data frames. Thus their vectors are treated as columns
>   rather than rows, and their inner names are ignored

Here, your `y` as constructed has only inner names - it is two unnamed list elements, each containing a length-one vector with the vector element named `a`. So this error seems to be expected.

If you name the list elements, you can see that it behaves as described, with the vectors treated as columns:

```r
library(tidyverse)
y <- map(1:2, ~ c(a=.x)) %>%
  set_names(c("a", "b"))
bind_rows(y)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
```

The difference with supplying `y` as arguments via `do.call` is that it's more like writing `bind_rows(c(a = 1), c(a = 2))`. This is not a list containing vectors, but separate vectors, so it binds by row as expected.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the definition of "inner name"?? Does that refer to the name attribute of a vector? That term doesn't appear in R-ints, R-lang, or R-intro.

Comment: Here it does, I believe. I don't think it is supposed to connote anything other than names of things inside the list elements, as opposed to the names of the elements. But because we're talking about a list of vectors, that means the names of the vectors.

Comment: Your answer also explains why rbind and cbind seemed to work backwards in this context.  I didn't mention it but it was pretty confusing. There are lots of twisty edges and dark corners in R :-)

Answer (score 6):

`bind_rows()` will also output the error `Error: Argument 1 must have names.` if you attempt to bind rows to a matrix instead of a data frame. Make sure you are not passing it a matrix.