# Purrr flatten_dfr

Tags: r, purrr, r-sf

I'm trying to extract a list of lists that hold coordinate information into a sf dataframe.

Here is the list

```
feature <- list(type = "Feature", properties = list(`_leaflet_id` = 26065L, 
feature_type = "polyline"), geometry = list(type = "LineString", 
coordinates = list(list(-74.210091, 40.382121), list(-73.942375, 
    40.661889))))
```

and I would like to convert it to a sf dataframe of 3 columns (leaflet_id, feature_type, geometry)

I've tried using purrr::flatten_dfr(feature) but get the error: argument 1 must have names.

I've reviewed other SO posts like below which seem promising but wasn't working.

Thanks

[Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505923/error-in-bind-rows-x-id-argument-1-must-have-names)

Comment: How would your expected output look for the data shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `feature` list looks like the result of reading `geojson` using something like `jsonlite::fromJSON()`.

If you read the `geojson` directly using `sf::st_read()` you'll get your `sf` object.

To fix your code as-is, you can do

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(sf)

sf <- jsonlite::toJSON( feature, auto_unbox = TRUE ) %>%
    sf::st_read()

sf
# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
# geometry type:  LINESTRING
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: -74.21009 ymin: 40.38212 xmax: -73.94238 ymax: 40.66189
# z_range:        zmin: NA zmax: NA
# m_range:        mmin: NA mmax: NA
# geographic CRS: WGS 84
# _leaflet_id feature_type                       geometry
# 1       26065     polyline LINESTRING (-74.21009 40.38...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your list that will throw errors with `flatten_dfr`.

1. Not all of your nested lists are named.  The two lists in `coordinates` need names.
2. You use the list name `type` twice.  This won't work, because your data frame after `flatten` will have two columns with the same name.

If you fix those issues, `flatten_dfr` will run without error:

```r
feature <- list(type = "Feature", 
                properties = list(`_leaflet_id` = 26065L, 
                                  feature_type = "polyline"), 
                geometry = list(type1 = "LineString", 
                                coordinates = list(foo=list(-74.210091, 40.382121), 
                                                   bar=list(-73.942375, 
 
flatten_dfr(feature)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  type    `_leaflet_id` feature_type type1      coordinates 
  <chr>           <int> <chr>        <chr>      <named list>
1 Feature         26065 polyline     LineString <list [2]>  
2 Feature         26065 polyline     LineString <list [2]>
```