# Bind_rows over 3 dataframes, resulting in error (Argument 1 must have names)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 3 data sets as such

```
**DF1**                            
        pt1     pt2            
A       1.5     2.2   

**DF2**
        pt1      pt2      pt3  
B       40       22       23  


**DF3**
        pt2      pt3      pt4      pt5
C       23       43       12       65 
D       12       04       13       34


IDEAL OUTPUT

        pt1      pt2      pt3      pt4     pt5
A       1.5      2.2      NA       NA      NA
B       0        22       23       NA      NA
C       NA       23       43       12      65
D       NA       12       04       13      34
```

When I try to bind_rows however I get this error

```
df_list <- list(DF1, DF2, DF3)

df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)

Error: Argument 1 must have names
```

I have tried looking this up but keep running into dead ends. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you print the output of `dput` applied to each of the 3 data frames? I believe something like `purrr::reduce(df_list, dplyr::bind_rows)` should work

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, both `bind_rows(df1,df2,df3)` (not what you tried) and `bind_rows(list(df1,df2,df3))` work for me without error. To know why this is happening to you, it would be beneficial to have the "real" unambiguous structure of the frame. Please use `dput(.)` on each `df*` and post the output in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505923/error-in-bind-rows-x-id-argument-1-must-have-names
It might be that one or several of your dfs are built from unamed list, probably the first column with the capital letters.

Comment: I do think the naming issue is the problem. I have thousands of columns, so is there a way I can post an abbreviated dput?

Comment: `dput(dat[1:3,1:5])`?

Comment: DF1 dput```structure(list(pt1 = c(23, NA, NA), pt2 = c4, 
NA, NA), pt3 = c(23, NA, NA), pt4 = c(2, 
NA, NA), pt5 = c(1, NA, NA)), row.names = c("row one", 
"NA", "NA.1"), class = "data.frame")``` Im not sure what the NAs are, it is only one row...

Comment: It is the same data structure for the other two DFs. The class is dataframe because I coerced it to ```as.data.frame()```, but if I dont do that then when I put ```dput(df1 [1:3, 1:5])``` , i get the error ```subscript out of bounds```

Comment: Your data has list-columns, so joins are likely to have problems. (Plus the `structure(.)` in your previous comment is incomplete, is has mis-matched parens.)

Comment: If it looked like this, should it work? ```structure(list(a = "10", B= "23", C = "43"), row.names = "row 1", class = "data.frame")```

Comment: *That* one looks normal.

Comment: Okay, so I generated DF1 by using ```df1 <- df %>% select(A) %>%
  t() ```  because I essentially am just trying to generate a subsetted dataset with dplyr. How do I change this so it doesnt give me list-columns?

Comment: `t()` breaks `data.frame`s. Have you ever looked at the contents to see how the contents (`class` of each column) changes? Compare `str(iris)` with `str(t(iris))` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, your code works.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 1)
df2 <- data.frame(b = 2, c = 2)
df3 <- data.frame(c = 3, d = 3)

dplyr::bind_rows(df1,df2, df3)
```

provides the following output

```
   a  b  c  d
1  1  1 NA NA
2 NA  2  2 NA
3 NA NA  3  3
```

The `Error: Argument 1 must have names` comes when you're not using a named structure. Can you confirm that your data frames are indeed data frames by checking them with

```
names(df1)
```

If you get `NULL`, then that is the problem.

---

As per your comment. If you use the `t()` function, it doesn't output a data frame, so you'll need to explicitly convert it to a data frame.

`dta %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()`

Comment: I did get null for the df1 and df2.... dput in the comments above....edit: null for all 3 dfs

Comment: with your last comment, make sure the last product is a data frame, not just a matrix/character.  `df1 <- df %>% select(A) %>%   t()  %>% as.data.frame()`.  The t() function outputs a matrix/vector

Comment: Now I think I have a different issue, which says ```Error: Can't combine `..1$A` <double> and `..2$A` <character>.``` I can ask this is a different question thread unless you think it is an easy answer. Thank you!

Comment: you'll need to make sure they're all consistent type. The safer thing is to convert 1$A to a character using `as.character()` and then binding rows.

Comment: Thank you, I foresee the problem being with multiple columns however.

Comment: then change them all to characters